# Input which fills all the available height

Tags: html, css, height

I want to set the height of my textarea "comment-rdv" so that it occupies the available height of its parent "col-lg-6". Here is my current code :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 zone-padding">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <div class="info-rdv">Text 1</div>
        <div class="info-rdv">Text 2</div>
        <div class="info-rdv">Text 3</div>
        <div class="info-rdv">
            <b>Comment :</b>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="commentaire-rdv">Not defined</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 zone-padding">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-content inner-content-div"> <!-- height = 320px; -->
                <!-- content -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you please add your current CSS and what you've tried so far to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by making the container flex and giving the textarea `flex-grow:1` (use full page in snippet below or bootply link and view on desktop):

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");

/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.zone-padding {
  border:1px solid red;
}
/* below 2 styles are to get equal height columns */
.box-content {
  height:320px;
}
.zone-padding {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

/*below styles are to get textarea to fill div*/
.info-rdv.flex {
  flex-grow:1;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.info-rdv.flex textarea {
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 zone-padding">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <div class="info-rdv">Text 1</div>
        <div class="info-rdv">Text 2</div>
        <div class="info-rdv">Text 3</div>
        <div class="info-rdv flex">
            <b>Comment :</b>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="commentaire-rdv">Not defined</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 zone-padding">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-content inner-content-div"> <!-- height = 320px; -->
                <!-- content -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Example bootply](https://www.bootply.com/4qbHpqOt39)